# Calculate the variance of an integer vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, integer

I need to calculate the variance of a large vector which is stored as `uint8`. The MATLAB `var` function however only accepts `double` and `single` types as input. The easiest way to calculate the variance would therefore be

```
vec = randi(255,1,100,'uint8');
var(single(vec))
```

This of course gives the correct result. However using `single` datatype increses the memory usage by a factor of 4. For large vectors (~ 1 million elements) this will quickly fill up the memory.

What I tried: The definition of the variance for a discrete random variable X is

[image: Definition] (Source: Wikipedia)

I estimated the `p`'s using the histogram, but then got stuck: To calculate the variance in a vectorized fashion, I would need to convert the `x_i`'s to `single` or `double`.

Is there any possibility to calculate the variance without converting the whole vector to `single` or `double`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to work with uint16, you can do this, it creates only 3 floating point numbers (var and the 2 means), use Var(X)=Mean(X^2)-Mean(X)^2:

```
uivec=uint16(vec);
mean(uivec.^2)-mean(uivec)^2
```

So, not as good as keeping uint8 but still twice better than converting to single. It should work with uint16 because your input is uint8 and (2^8)^2=2^16.

If you want the exact same answer as var, you need to remember that MATLAB uses the unbiased estimator for var (it divides the sum by `n-1` instead of `n`, where `n` is your number of samples) so you need to do:

```
n=length(vec);
v=mean(uivec.^2)-mean(uivec)^2*(n/(n-1))
```

then your `v` will be exactly equal to `var(single(vec))`.

Comment: This does not give the variance!

Comment: It should, don't you think? But it would require `int32` precision, which is 4 bytes, just as `single`, so same memory usage.

Comment: so yeah still not better regarding memory usage :(

Comment: and the answer is not 100% precise. However its a good trick to know. Deleted down-vote.

Comment: Just a second: with the way you propose, it would be possible to use `uint16`, instead of `uint32`. The maximum of `uivec.^2` is `255^2=65025`, which fits inside `uint16`. So half memory usage. (Though I also figured it is not 100% exact)

Comment: yeah I was thinking the same thin uint16 is enough! but still not getting why it is not exact.

Comment: You can actually make it "exact", it's just that matlab uses an unbiased estimator and not the formula.

Answer (score 1):

No. The value of the variance is going to be a floating point value most likely, so you need to perform floating point operations.

`p_i` itself is the Probability mass function, so `sum(p_i)` should be one, therefore each `p_i` is a floating point number.

In addition, `nu`, the mean, will probably not be integer neither

Comment: It's true that it obviously isn't possible to calculate the exact variance - but it might be possible to get an estimate. Besides, `p_i` is the probability density, not `x_i`.